# How can I hook into a close event on v-menu

Tags: events, menu, vuetify.js, event-hooking

I'm building a vue.js application with Vuetify 1.5.2. I have a v-menu (https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus) on which I would like to hook into a close event. I'm not seeing a close event in the documentation. Does anyone know if there is a close event or something equivalent on the v-menu for Vuetify 1.5.2?

Thanks

Comment: Hey did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In version 2 of Vue, I was able to implement this feature by adding an `@input` event listener to the `v-menu` component. For example:

```html
<v-menu
  ...
  @input="handleMenuInput"
>
```

In the corresponding script section:

```js
handleMenuInput(input) {
  const closing = !input;
  if (closing) {
    this.doSomethingYouLike();
  }
}
```

With this implementation, whenever the `v-menu` component is interacted with (e.g., opened or closed), the `handleMenuInput` method will be called. The `handleMenuInput` function checks if the input parameter is false, indicating that the menu is closing. If it is closing, the method proceeds to execute `this.doSomethingYouLike()`.

Please note that this solution may not be compatible with the version of Vue mentioned in the original question, but I hope it provides some guidance. Enjoy!